# Maven build is not generating main class files in JAR file-could not find or load main class error

Tags: java, maven

The build was successful without any errors, but I checked the Jar file and there was no class files in it.

I the following command to

```
$mvn package command
```

with the following POM.xml :

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.cms.service.utils</groupId>
  <artifactId>CMS_Job</artifactId>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>CMS_Job</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>CMS_Job</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>

                  <includes>
                    <include>**/log4j.properties</include>
                  </includes>
                  <archive>
                    <manifest>
         <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
         <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
         <mainClass>com.cms.service.utils.App</mainClass> 
       </manifest>
                  </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                        <configuration>
                      <!-- exclude junit, we need runtime dependency only -->
                      <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                      <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And this is my folder structure is described in the image(Linked)

[image: directory structure]

This is how my jar file contents look like(Check the path on top)

[image: jar content]

I am new to maven environment.

Please help

Comment: what if you remove classpathprefix?

Comment: This is probably unrelated, but the Maven Eclipse Plugin has been obsolete for years. Instead, use m2eclipse, which can understand and write POM files.